# How can I remove the File Quarantine warning for a file associated with an Automator script?

Tags: automator

To download torrents, I have changed from running Transmission on my Mac to running it on a NAS. As a next step, I want the Mac to automatically start the torrent download on the NAS by moving the .torrent file to the "watch folder" on the NAS.

I have created the Automator script below to move the file and it works well. I have associated .torrent files with this script and my browser (Chrome) opens these automatically.

[image: Automator script]

The problem I now have is that the Mac File Quarantine is triggered when the .torrent file is opened. I get the message:

> ".torrent" may be an application. It was
>   downloaded from the Internet and will be opened by
>   TorrentOnDiskstation. Are you sure you want to open it?

When I have Transmission installed on my Mac, it opens .torrent files without a warning message, so it must have some way of telling the OS that .torrent files are ok.

How can I get the same behavior with my Automator script?

I've found answers that show how to completely disable the File Quarantine feature (at least for pre-Lion Mac OS), but this seems overkill. I've also seen "hacks" that will trigger the xattr function when a file is created, but this doesn't seem elegant. Can anyone come up with a clean and self-contained solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the Terminal.

`defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO`

This will turn off the warning permanently, or until you change it back with the following command.

`defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool YES`

You may need to restart for changes to take effect. Info from [MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/145324/2010/01/filewarnings.html).

Comment: on a per-file-basis would be nice, though. This is system-wide, right?

Comment: Yes, this is system-wide. For a per file or I think per folder solution try `xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /path/to/folder_or_file`.